# AppleScript: Display alert or restart when application terminates/crashes?

Tags: macos, applescript, crash, script

I rely on Dropbox for syncing work files between two computes that are powered on 24/7. For some reason, Dropbox terminates (crashes or quits) after long periods of time, with no explanation. I just find later that the application is no longer running.

Is there a way I can get notified (e.g. via a popup) when a certain application terminates?

I'm thinking there might be a way for AppleScript to do this, but I'm unsure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easily with an Applescript:

```
 repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        if name of every process does not contain "Dropbox" then display alert "Dropbox has crashed!"
    end tell
    delay 5
end repeat
```

You could replace "display alert" with `tell application 'Dropbox' to launch` ..to have it automatically restart if you desire.

Paste this into `Script Editor`. save it, and then you could add the script to your user's startup items for future use. The timing there may be a bit tricky though if the script starts before Dropbox - adding a `delay 10` or something before the first `repeat` would solve this.

For future use, anything involving `System Events` is a great place to look for solutions to these kinds of meta-system-wide tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now implemented your solution so that it automatically restarts the application, and it seems to work great.